# Android TextView encoding

Tags: android, sqlite, encoding

After creating a database, i'm using a listview do display some lines of it. I'm facing a encoding problem trying to display a 'Ç' or 'ç' and many other characters. What is the correct approach to solve the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to convert all the text you have to UTF-8. Android's default charset is UTF-8 and you can configure your tools (eclipse, operating system default encoding, etc.) to always use UTF-8 - this way any text you will be entering or copying into files will be UTF-8 and your worries are much less.

If you have some other external data sources like files or HTML pages, you should convert them to UTF-8 first. There are number of tools you can use - various text editors for Windows/OSX (Notepad++ my favourite), iconv unix command line tool etc. to convert between various encodings.

UTF-8 is also used by JSON which is most commonly used format for mobiles for data exchange.

Comment: What do you mean by escaped text?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check [defaultCharset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) vs your desired charset.

and you have the [Charset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) utility at your disposal.